# Two way data binding doesn't work from directive link function angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm trying to use variable declared in directive' `link: function` in directive view html.

Variable which I'm trying to use is int from object which is (this object) declared as $scope variable named slider.

I'm trying to display it:

```
<div>
    {{ slider.step }}
</div>
```

And printed value is `aa : 1` and it's not changing althougt it should be. It's constantly 1 and it don't want to rebind :( although I'm changing this value in code later on. Take a look at full directive code. I'm changing its value in few places:

..in directive link function..

```
link: function($scope, el) {
  $scope.slider = {
    step: 1,
    changeSlide: function (step) {
      if(step === 1) {
        this.step = 1;
        console.log('changed step to 1: ' + $scope.slider.step);
      }
      if(step === 2) {
        this.step = 2;
        console.log('changed step to 2: ' + $scope.slider.step);
      }
    }
  }
  $timeout(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $scope.slider.changeSlide(i);
    setInterval(function () {
        i++; if(i === 3) i = 1;
        $scope.slider.changeSlide(i);
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

I'm chaning step in `if(step === 2)`.

Basically that's correctly working vertical slider. The only missing thing is that I can't access current step from view and I can't display correct active dot of "which slide is currently selected". That's why I need to get this step int in view but I can not.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ud2wWoD87WqmSRDy9A4i?p=preview) is plnkr demo.

Comment: Add some `console.log`s where you change its value. Maybe you initiate it wrong!

Comment: I add console.log just after this.step = 2 and it did console 2 but it didn't rerender in html template. it show 1 and don't want to change i'm doing somethig wrong

Comment: Can you provide a working plunker or codepen example?

Comment: Yes sure. Here you go. I didn't use code from original source but I created Minimal example of issue. Look at console when you fire this script. https://plnkr.co/edit/Ud2wWoD87WqmSRDy9A4i?p=preview It is changing in JS code but it is not rerendering in template that's why title of this question is 2 way data binding doesn't work :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `$timeout(function(){ $scope.$apply(); });` after data changed

Working example

```js
angular.module('plunker', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'World';
}

angular.module('plunker').directive('elements', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    template: `<div>
    {{ slider }}
</div>`,
    link: function($scope, el) {

      $scope.slider = {
        step: 1,
        changeSlide: function(step) {
          console.log(11, step)
          if (step === 1) {
            this.step = 1;
            console.log('changed step to 1: ' + $scope.slider.step);
          }
          if (step === 2) {
            this.step = 2;
            console.log('changed step to 2: ' + $scope.slider.step);
          }
          $timeout(function(){ $scope.$apply(); });
        }
      }
      var i = 1;

      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.slider.changeSlide(i);
        setInterval(function() {
          i++;
          if (i === 3) i = 1;
          $scope.slider.changeSlide(i);
        }, 5000);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
    document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <elements></elements>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it did but why I have to use this is weird

Comment: And also https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle @BT101

Comment: I'm now getting error when I init function not inside interval but by ng-click `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: So your problem changed to something else now. search this new one. I'll search too @BT101

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171970/discussion-between-saeed-ataee-and-bt101).